# prove equation for idempotent P

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to prove this:  $A^2=I \Leftrightarrow A=2P-I$ for a idempotent P.  ($\Rightarrow P^2=P$)

Solution: 
$\Rightarrow$: I just insert  $A=2P-I$: $A^2=(2P-I)^2=4P^2-4PI-I^2=4P-4P-I=I$

$\Leftarrow$:  $A^2-I=0$

$(A-I)(A+I)=0$

And now I don't know how to continue. Please help me.

Comment: What you proved first is $\Leftarrow$, not $\Rightarrow$. For the other direction, how could you express $P$ in terms of $A$, in order to check that it is idempotent?

Answer (score 1):

You have one direction, for the other, just use the formula given to get $P={1\over2} (A+I)$. Since $P$ is idempotent, we have 
$P^2={1 \over 4} (A^2+2A+I) = {1 \over 2} (A+I)$. Simplifying gives the result.

Answer (score 1):

Note tht $(A+I)^2 = A^2 + 2 A + I = 2(A+I).$ So, $(A+1)/2$ is idempotent.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Well, working backwards and assuming $A^2=I$, you would naturally try $P:=(A+I)/2$. Squaring this, you'll discover $P^2=P$ and $A=2P-I$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ \ \color{#c00}{P^2 = P} \iff \left(\dfrac{A+1}2\right)^2\! = \dfrac{A+1}2 \iff A^2\!+2A+1 = 2A+2 \iff \color{#c00}{A^2 = 1}$